# How to stack left-nav-bars with 3col fixed layout?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I stack nav bars on top of eachother given the following fiddle?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VkvX3/

This is photoshopped in the red but it's what I want to achieve
[image]

I have tried wrapping two stacked in  and  but no go.

```
    <div class="???">
      <div class="well sidebar-nav left">
        <ul class="nav nav-list"> 
          // o o o
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="well sidebar-nav left">
        <ul class="nav nav-list"> 
          // o o o
        </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would scaffolding like this work for you?
http://www.bootply.com/68303

Basically the two lefthand nav blocks are in the same span, the right hand nav is in its own span, and the central block is in nested container.

I'm sure you will want to customise this further, though if you use the standard bootstrap grid as much as possible everything will stack and scale well on narrow screens.

Good luck!

Comment: Awesome! That worked. Check this fiddle->http://jsfiddle.net/GwCkp/18/.  However, right now I'm setting the main container's width (first line in .html) to 1300px.  This works nicely but how can I resize the middle part more elegantly.  I need that middle part (hero and content to stay no less than ~640px as there will be a chart in there with other widgets so I want that fixed. Setting the width of that hero-unit or the parent container-fluid did't seem to work.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, do you know how I can decrease the whitespace between nav bars and between the navbars and the main hero unit?  The main buffer space between contained units?  (i.e. I want the left navbar right margin closer to the main hero unit).

Comment: For some reason this layout is a beast for the middle to resize.  I just want the middle container to stay at 650 and the entire container to stay within 1100px.  Maybe I'm missing something here but I'm not seeing a lot of benefit with bootstrap and fluid/responsive/static layouts. Tables are a heck of lot easier to use but I'm sure I'm missing something here since this is the first I've used bootstrap.

Comment: See if this variation helps: http://www.bootply.com/68384 . I've added classes to the outer container and the middle column to control their max and min widths

Comment: I really appreciate the info. That works.  However, when I try the same to adjust the navbars on the side the spans get all out of alignment.  I'm new to bootstrap and responsive formats but it seems like a lot of heuristic styling pain.

Comment: Not only that but the spacing between the units.  It all seems a bit heuristic to me. However, maybe I need to go back to bootsrap school and revisit basics.

Comment: Much of the challenge is because you've chosen a difficult layout to work with as the viewport narrows (left navs, centre column that needs to be min width, and right nav). It's hard to fit it all in. I'll think about it ;)

Comment: Another variation that has good potential: http://www.bootply.com/68507 . Note that the right hand nav block now appears in the HTML before the hero unit and we pull it to the right for wide screens. When there isn't enough space for everything (viewports < 990px) we make the nav bars full width and above the main content. If this structure looks promising to you, it should be easy enough the fine-tune the spacing and other details you mention.